# Title space of List of listings is too small

Tags: spacing, listings, titles

I am encountering the problem that the space between the title and the actual list is too small no matter what I do. But this issue only exists regarding the list of listings. All other lists (e.g. the list of tables) have the correct space (see picture). I am using the packages `tocstyle` and `listings` by the way.

Any idea what I am doing wrong here?

```
\documentclass[paper = a4, 12pt, twoside, parskip, toc = bibliography, openany]{scrbook}

\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{tocstyle}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

%% Table of contents
\setstretch{0.9}
\tableofcontents
\newpage

%% List of ToDos
\listoftodos
\newpage

%% List of tables
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Tabellenverzeichnis}
\let\LaTeXStandardClearpage\clearpage
\let\clearpage\relax
\listoftables
\vspace*{0.5cm}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Quellcodeverzeichnis}
\lstlistoflistings
\let\clearpage\LaTeXStandardClearpage
\newpage

\end{document}
```

[image: Red Arrow showing where the spacing is too small]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please provide us a Minimal Working Example (MWE). It is especially necessary to know what packages you use, because this affects the way how things are compiled. An MWE starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}`. “MWE” does *not* mean that you put just every line of your code here, but just enough so that we (the users of this platform) can replicate your problem.

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer. I tried to build up a MWE, but in that everything works fine and I don't have a spacing issue. The problem though is that this MWE is far away from my actual document. I am using a lot of Packages and a long Preamble. I got a template from a friend of mine for my master thesis. It works very well and of course I also customized a lot. But I simply can't reproduce my problem in like a short example. Before I wrote this question I was trying everything I could to solve the problem by myself and also search for any kind of solutions online, but couldn't find one :(

Comment: The problem seems like very random. As I am aware the listing package is using the TOC. And in that no weird spacing is happening. Is there any way to just 'force' some title spacing before \lstlistoflistings ?

Comment: Hi Fabi, welcome to TeX.SX! It is hard (or even impossible) for any user here to solve your problem without seeing the parts of the code that cause it. From the code you posted, I don't see anything that would cause the effect you describe. The only way forward is for you to "hack down" your actual document by removing part for part until you isolated the lines that cause the problem, i.e. where the problem vanishes if you delete the lines. You can have a look at articles that describe this in more detail, e.g. https://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/minexample/html/hackingdown.html

Comment: Ok I looked deeper into it and found one aspect of the problem, but still don't know why the spacing is different at this place. As this all is too much time consuming right now especially for such a little detail, I just went with a workaround by inserting  a chapter title manually with     \fontspec{Calibri}\huge\textbf{Quellcodeverzeichnis}
    \fontspec{Cambria}\normalsize and setting the official title empty with \renewcommand{\lstlistlistingname}{} not a very nice solution but working :) thanks again for your efforts